# Spring batch with pagination creates duplicate entries

Tags: spring, pagination, duplicates, spring-batch

We have spring batch which fetches data from tables using Jpa pagination and publishes to Kafka topic

It was noted that after adding pagination we are getting many duplicate entries in Kafka

Batch item reader has chunk size 5000 and page size is define as 10. Currently there is no sort order in pagerequest
What could be the probable reason batch now sending duplicates?

We do not expect any duplicates

Comment: Without code details, it would not be possible to guess the reason of the described behaviour. Please provide more details to be able to help you efficiently.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.